# iOS - Detect shake anywhere in the application

Tags: ios4, gesture-recognition, gestures, shake

Is it possible to detect a shake gesture, no matter of the view displayed?

I want to go to the main page of the app whenever the user shakes the device.
Is there any other solution besides putting in each UIView the `-motionBegan:withEvent:` method?

Comment: Xcode (not xCode) is an IDE - are you talking about iOS perhaps ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a subclass of `UIViewController`, say `UIShakeViewController`, and derive all your view controller classes from `UIShakeViewController`.

Then, in `UIShakeViewController`, implement your shake detection methods, etc. This way, all your view controllers have the functionality, but you implement the detection code once.

Comment: I end up subclassing UIWindow.